# PDFSharp Concatenate documents with different size pages

Tags: pdf, concatenation, pdfsharp

I have a scenario where I need to concatenate documents that are uploaded by users. There appear to be two pages sizes, similar to A4 and similar to A5.

Those documents on A4 page size appear to have A5 content on A4 page.

How could I increase the A5 pages up to the A4 size while copying pages from my import document to my output document thus creating a consistent volume.

Cheers,

Mark

Answer (score 0):

In the new document you can create A4 pages only and draw the pages from the imported documents as large as they fit.

You can look at the Two Pages on One sample:
http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/TwoPagesOnOne-sample.ashx

Your task is much simpler than the sample, so you leave a lot of the code away - but it should give you a general idea.
The main point: You can draw imported PDF pages using `gfx.DrawImage()`.